# Difference between channel.isOpen() and channel.isConnected() in Netty?

Tags: java, netty

Netty defines two methods for channels: isOpen() and isConnected(), but the [Javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/Channel.html) does not really explain the difference between both and it is not self-explanatory. Can anyone clarify?

Is the following true?

-) An open channel is always connected

-) A connected channel does not mean one can use it to communicate, it must be open too

-) UDP-like channels are never connected

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's incorrect, a channel can be open and not connected, but a connected channel is necessarily open.

You can send data to an open channel that is not connected for connectionless transports using the `write` method that takes a `SocketAddress` as a parameter. Otherwise the channel needs to already be open and connected.

Comment: OK. So, if a channel is open, it is a SUFFICIENT condition to consider it available for read/write operations regardless of its connected status, correct?

Comment: @JVerstry: no, it's not. That is only the case **if** it's a connection-less transport **and** you're using the correct `write` method. Otherwise if must be open **and** connected.